# What does というのは、[...]のことを mean in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, meaning

The sentence is

> というのは、スプーンのことをやまと言葉では「かい」といいます。

I understand the general meaning, but can't get these two things:

1. the meaning of というのは in the beginning;
2. why を is used in

   > スプーンのことを

Could anyone help me please?

Answer (score 6):

"というのは" means "This is because." There should be another sentence before this.

"を" is used in the pattern of "AをBという", which means "we call A B."